# Client added an image to WordPress header and not aligning properly

Tags: html, css, wordpress

my client has added an image to their WordPress header. I am having difficulty (I'm still learning CSS) getting the image to align where we want it.

[This is the site here](http://marijuanaindex.org)

You can see the Options House graphic on the right. I want it to be to the right of the word "stocks" in the tagline. Help?

====Edits based upon suggestions below====

@Beardminator made a suggested answer, but this is what the site header looked like after including that code:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relatively position that options_house div like so:

```
#options_house {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
    left: 52px;
}
```

And take off the overflow hidden from the header class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the 2 div which you should replace with this code:

```
.slogan {
    color: #EBEBEB;
    font-size: 17px;
    left: 200px;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 4px #0F243E;
    top: 59px;
}


.logo_mmj, .logo_mmj:visited, .logo_mmj:hover, .logo_mmj:visited:hover {
    background: url("../images/logo_marijuana.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    height: 95px;

    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    top: 23px;
    width: 392px;
}
```

You need to put the logo to the right, so the `.logo_mmj` should contain

```
  right:0px;
```

Or if you use position:relative;
You can use like this:

```
.logo_mmj
{
 position:relative;
 float:right;
}
```

update:
The site you linked have very different logo that's why It only made it worse. You only need to adjust 
.slogan  left property. And add 
to .logo_mmj div top:30px or much more.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but that makes the problem worse. I have edited my post and added a screenshot of what happens when I add the above code.

Comment: i updated my answer. the site you linked have much different logo then what i see.